# Java - Map<String, List<Object>> iterate through list and skip first N entries

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java so please be lenient. I have a map, Map<K,V>. I need to iterate through the values, skip the first N indices and add what remains to another list for processing.

For example

```
Key:   foo
Value: [id=001, name=Fred, job=Mailman, age=51],
       [id=002, name=Johan, job=Musician, age=335],
       [id=003, name=Alice, job=Finance, age=49],
       [id=004, name=Marcus, job=Developer, age=41]
```

I'm sorting by age in descending order and I need to skip over the first N list entries.

The code below is where I'm currently at. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
List<Object> finalList = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> sortedList = new ArrayList<Object>();

Map<String, List<Object> map = getMapFn();

for(List<Object> anotherList : map.values()) {
   Collections.reverse(anotherList);
   sortedList = anotherList;

   for(Object o : sortedList) {
      int skipN = N;

      for(int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
         if(i < skipN) {
            continue;
         }
      }
      finalList.add(o);
   }
}
```

Final Goal:

```
If N=2,
finalList = [id=003, name=Alice, job=Finance, age=49],
[id=004, name=Marcus, job=Developer, age=41]
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code sections. Questions that are not well formatted are less likely to be answered :)

Comment: What is the class for the objects in the lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code,item in sortedList will always add to  finalList

```
   int skipN = N;
   int index = 0;
   for(Object o : sortedList) {
      if(index<skipN){
          index++;
          contine;
      }
      index++;
      finalList.add(o);
   }
```

or use jdk1.8 stream

```
sortedList.stream().skip(skipN).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop at all.

```
  int skipN = N;
  for(Object o : sortedList) {
      if (skipN-- > 0) {
         continue;
      }
      finalList.add(o);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd and 3rd for loop will perform the same task. I think you do not want this.
So, remove 2nd loop. 3rd loop will be:

- get the Nth item from your `sortedList` using `sortedList.get(i)`
- And, add it into your `finalList`

```
for(int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
   if(i < skipN) {
      continue;
    }
   finalList.add(sortedList.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sublist of the items to remove and delete all items from it:

```
for (List<Object> list : map.values()) {
    Collections.reverse(list);
    list.subList(0, Math.min(list.size(), N)).clear();
}
```

This creates a sublist that contains the first `N` items (or the whole list if there are less than `N` items), then deletes all the items in the sublist via `.clear()`.

Modifications to sublists are reflected in the original list, so the deletions are reflected in the original list.

---

For interest sake, here's a one-line version:

```
map.values().stream()
    .peek(Collections::reverse)
    .map(list -> list.subList(0, Math.min(list.size(), N))
    .forEach(List::clear);
```

but it doesn't look as clear as the multi-line version above.